# App name displayed in ReplayKit permissions

Tags: ios, replaykit

I'm working on an app which records the user's screen using ReplayKit.  When the permissions modal pops up, it displays the wrong app name.

So, if my app were named, "foo", for example, I'd want the persmissions dialog to display: Allow screen recording in "Foo"?  But it doesn't use the string "Foo" -- it says: Allow screen recording in "PhotoManager"?

Context: The build process is pretty complicated, so the string, "PhotoManager", is probably coming from somewhere I haven't identified.  But it's not the name of the app, it's not the bundle ID, and doesn't appear to be in any searchable text files.  I'm guessing "PhotoManager" was the name of a class someone made at some point (it's a large project);  but, I can't seem to figure out how that string is finding its way into the persmissions modal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you also checked `CFBundleName`?

Comment: Not directly -- the .plist only lives on our build machine (which yes, I need to check).  But usually CFBundleName is derived from the bundle ID, isn't it?  And if that were wrong, the signing would fail.  I'm gonna check, though... weird.

Comment: Huh, happens with a local build, too.  Welp, off to hunt down that .plist...

Comment: Ok, the CFBundleName is correct.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the last part of the bundle ID "PhotoManager" by any chance?

Comment: Nope.  "PhotoManager" was the name of a test app I made recently to play around with ReplayKit.  Somehow, my phone retained that string and used it in place of the app name in a *completely different app*.  After rebooting the phone, this did not persist, fortunately.  Very strange.